# dynamodb caching subsequent results

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

Is there any mechanism or buildin feature inside dynamodb where subsequent dynamodb query/scan calls with same request(key) can be cached?

eg:
If i make a query call to dynamodb for first time for key k1 and fetches the result r1 in t1 ms.
will the next subsequent call(second time within a sec following first time) to dynamodb with same key k1 result in shorter latency(t2 ms)?
is there a way to cache at dynamodb side? even if its not configurable by client ,does dynamodb atleast caches the result at its end for subsequent requests?

PS: I am not talking about DAX(dynamodb accelerator) cache, Just the normal dynamodb.

Comment: I would expect this to be a private implementation detail if you haven't been able to locate any documentation on it. Is there a particular issue with fetch latency that you are trying to solve?

Comment: no.. i wanted to compare dynamodb with another datastore solution specific to our organization. All i want to know is whether there is caching layer in dynamodb which caches subsequent calls. This is essential to consider weigh down the performance metrics between two data store solutions at my workplace

Comment: I think I would want to include a short study of actual latency metrics rather than rely purely on any particular statement on caching.

Comment: well, all i want to know if there is any caching layer at dynamodb and if it caches subsequent requests.. we have done the study of metrics. we wanted to know the reason behind some metrics

Comment: Sounds good. Out of interest, what do your metrics tell you?

Comment: that our datastore specific to our organization is better wrt latency in some scenarios for our usecases. and there is inbuilt caching solution in that datastore. wanted to know if our comparison is fair when dynamodb is without inbuilt cache.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is pretty clear, that DynamoDB's caching solution is Dax, as you have already stated the answer in the question.

Comment: i know that DAX is a caching solution offered to dynamodb..  i just wanted to know if they have caching mechanism internally and not external caching like DAX.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by internally, what would it matter to you any way you still pay for the capacity units, and performance is pretty consistent. The only thing which improves is the caching of partition locations for a given key I think, but improvements negligible.